# Need to OrderBy using Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I'm fairly new to Linq so go easy on me.  I'm creating a blog site rather than using a canned solution and i'm building it with MVC 3.  I have an archive page which displays posts by year.  In the repository, the code is:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Post>> groupedPosts = _dataContext.Posts
            .GroupBy(s => s.PostDate.Year)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Key).ToList();
```

As you can see, I am taking a list of posts and grouping them by year.  The key in this case is of course the year.  In the view, I loop over the collection and everything displays correctly.  However, I noticed that when I insert a new post, because I am ordering by year, the new post within the group is placed at the bottom and out of date order.  For example after inserting a post for April 20 2013, the archive displays the following:-

```
2013
Aha, I'm back
Posted: 15 April 2013
Aha, I'm back
Posted: 07 April 2013
Thinking Too Much
Posted: 02 March 2013
Blog 2 Title Category XHTML
Posted: 02 February 2013
Latest Blog Post
Posted: 20 April 2013
```

See how my latest post is placed at the bottom of the pile when it should be at the top of each grouping.  I know I need to order the posts somehow but am not sure how to do this.  Is there a simple way I can order the posts within each group, so the latest post is placed at the top of each group.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Post>> groupedPosts = _dataContext.Posts
  .AsEnumerable()  //we're pulling the whole table, might as well make it official.
  .OrderByDescending(s => s.PostDate)
  .GroupBy(s => s.PostDate.Year)  //Enumerable.GroupBy retains the order in the groups
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Arghhh.  I knew it would be something so simple but I couldn't see the woods for the trees.  Works absolutely spot on.  Cheers for that Dave

Answer (score 1):

You should order twice - one for items within each group, and second for groups:

```
var groupedPosts = _dataContext.Posts
            .GroupBy(s => s.PostDate.Year)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Key)
            .Select(g = new { g.Key, Items =  g.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostDate) })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I have tried this but the compiler insists I convert to a different type.  Specifically I get the following warning message: - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Model.Entities.Post>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<int,Model.Entities.Post>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).  I cannot then access the key property in the view if i perform this cast.

Comment: Change your variable declaration to implicit `var` and use anonymous type.

Comment: I have tried this also.  I actually created a specific view model for this purpose so i could map the values across.  Properties in the view model were year, title, date.  However, this means that instead of printing out one year followed by the grouped posts underneath and then another year etc, a year was printed out for every post which I do not want.  I have thought of workarounds but this would mean adding complex logic in the view which I believe is not best practice.